# render page while making http request express

Tags: node.js, express, httprequest

Hi i'm an express noob.... I have an api look page, that's all working but what i'd like to have is once a user hits the route i'll display a loading page, fire off the api http request then once it's successful redirect/render the results page. As i understand it you can't use res.render twice on the same route? Maybe our chum next(); can help here?

This is what i have so far:

```
router.get('/lookup/post/:url', function(req, res){

  // Render the loading page...?
  res.render('loading');

  Lookup.post(req.params.url, function(err, result){
    if(err){

    }else{
      // ...Then once the api lookup comes back ok redirect or render the results page?
      res.render('results', {
        posts : result.store.postData.posts[0],
        votes : result.store.voteData
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You can't render the page, once and then serenader it :) Remove the ` res.render('loading');`, and what you have is correct, this is how you do it. You display the page once the callback function is executed .

Comment: Thanks David, and sure, if i remove the res.render('loading') it works fine... but i do require a loading page. So would i render the loading page, then move to the next() middleware function.. like the http lookup which upon success renders the results page?

Comment: I don't think you can do that kind of page UI entirely from the server using `res.render()`.  You could move the `loading` from server to client so that the client shows the loading UI which is then replaced when the results of the POST come through.

Comment: Thanks the feedback  jfriend00, yeah i might let the server render the page which displays the loader, then maybe use the client to make an ajax call to the api and on success it can hide the loader and populate the page ... hmmm, as always there's more than one way to fry an egg...

Comment: For anyone wanting to do a similar thing. I have this working by using express to render the page, then on page load fire off an ajax call to another passing with it the url which on success hides the loader and uses a bit of jQuery to populate some divs on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to do part in the UI and part on the server. You can do it with an Ajax call or by using Socket.IO, which will create a socket connection to the server.

I would argue that the later is the most convenient solution, because you can talk to the back-end and the front-end by emitting and listening to messages. The cool part of Socket.IO is that if the browser doesn't support sockets, it will default to an Ajax call.

The official website of Socket.IO is: http://socket.io. You can also check my [bPhone](https://github.com/davidgatti/bPhone) project where I use Socket.IO in the simplest way possible. Plus my code have a lot of comments that should make everything super clear.

I hope this will put you on the right path :)

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the response. Yes a lot clearer on it now. I got it working with Ajax but i hadn't considered socket.io i have used that before with a twitter streaming API project and yes, the plus side is the ajax fallback! thanks again man!

Comment: No worries, glad to help. Don't forget to up-vote my answer :)